# Limit number of active tasks in Celery

Tags: python, celery

Having task

```py
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery(__name__, **kwargs) # Some setting here probably?

@celery.task(name="task_runner", bind=True)
def generic_task(self, function_type):
    task_id = self.request.id
    # Do whatever
    if function_type == 1:
        high_ram_usage_1() # Really a high memory function
    if function_type == 2:
        high_ram_usage_2() # Another high memory function
    # Other functions
```

How to limit the active task count to two for the whole celery app? Only two active functions fit in my memory which eventually crashes the server on my development computer.

EDIT:

```py
celery = Celery(__name__, concurrency=2) # Does not work
celery.conf.update(concurrency=2) # Does not work
@celery.task(concurrency=2) # Does not work
def dummy_task(self):
    time.sleep(5)
```

Worker logs

```
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[b62052bf-c893-4ad4-bc30-cffaa39bcbb1] succeeded in 5.110082127997885s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[a2def96d-6306-422a-be79-14f43886aa7f] succeeded in 5.104002231993945s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[4b377742-c22f-432c-a675-9c0dbdd2cb41] succeeded in 5.119215640006587s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[5735de81-79f7-43ac-b28c-42cb071011ca] succeeded in 5.139429216011195s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[5b37c19f-693d-45d4-8580-6b493632c5ab] succeeded in 5.142507184995338s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[d8b00cfc-0773-43cd-bc40-d5a55a1dfda0] succeeded in 5.158245797007112s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[0d93b652-b4f9-4bff-97b5-0660cdc05586] succeeded in 5.168131768004969s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[b7946f28-7df6-42d8-9a9d-1e7b5efc3a4a] succeeded in 5.173699700011639s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[4f1f9389-040a-45dd-b252-4342ba1d3445] succeeded in 5.187171609024517s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[6651040f-bffa-46b6-ab4f-950d8f518b46] succeeded in 5.192372458986938s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[b65d2de1-5029-47f7-8048-73c4c38065ad] succeeded in 5.279150495975045s: True
<redacted>:Task dummy_task[3211729b-e8b9-4c72-9354-caf16e7a6970] succeeded in 6.117392421991099s: True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the number of tasks that runs in celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283696/how-to-limit-the-number-of-tasks-that-runs-in-celery)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I do not spawn these functions from command line.

Comment: Did you actually seriously read the answer to the question @TharunK pointed at? - No matter how you run your Celery worker there MUST be a way to configure it with `concurrency=2` - precisely what that answer suggests!

Comment: Yes, of course I did. Some would consider suggesting otherwise unpolite and rude, especially in condescending tone. I tested as a keyword to `Celery`-object, tried to update `.conf` and pass this keyword to the `task` decorator. None of these worked and I can still see mock `sleep` functions returning at the same time.

Comment: Furthermore, by doing `control.inspect` I can observe all spawned tasks to be in active state.

Comment: You could use a dedicated queue for these critical tasks, with a single consumer (worker). What exactly do you mean with "I do not spawn these functions from command line"? How do you run your application? Do you use docker-compose or  minikube or how do you launch your broker and the workers? And how do you create the tasks?

Comment: You were trying to set concurrency on a task, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify concurrency on a task, so `@celery.task(concurrency=2)` does not work.
The thread @TharunK pointed at have already answer to your question as you have the same problem. However, it seems you did not fully understand it.

What the answer to that thread basically says is that you need to configure your Celery worker to spawn no more than N worker processes. In your case N=2.

There are few ways to do it, one of them is the [--concurrency](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/cli.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-c) command-line option of Celery worker.

You have been quite close to set it up using the configuration object, but you used the wrong key. The correct key is [worker_concurrency](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker-concurrency) so `celery.conf.update(worker_concurrency=2)` should do the job.

Comment: What I tried to actually achieve is that at maximum two heavy duty tasks are on and a set of lower consumption functions may also be active at the same time. My question may have been ill-defined due to lack of understanding. I was also very frustrated which did affect my conduct.

Comment: The answer here is correct for the question presented.